# Unable to publish on user's facebook wall through blackberry application

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I want to publish a post to user's wall..for this first i am making user to log in and getting the session id also...but in order to publish i need the user to grant me publish_stream permission..so immmediately after i am obtaining auth_token by capturing url of the login success screen, i am making call to http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php? with "api_key","ext_perm","display" as parameteres..but when the above url is redirected and displayed on BrowserField i am seeing "Incompatible web browser " instead of the permission granting dialog or popup..i will be greatful if anyone can help...thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

To get the extended permissions granted, use this URL instead:

http://m.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=APPKEY&connect_display=page&v=1.0&cancel_url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html&fbconnect=true&return_session=true&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permission.php?api_key=APPKEY&ext_perm=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?xxRESULTTOKENxx

Notice that the 'next' variable points to http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permission.php and xxRESULTTOKENxx will be replaced by the granted permissions (you should check this to confirm the requested permissions are granted).

Answer (score 0):

Making hand-constructed calls to facebook endpoints is tricky.  Sometimes they need you to pass cookies that are in the facebook.com domain (impossible if you are an iframe web app), and they have other requirements like the one you hit, which I have also encountered.

The "incompatible web browser" error is because you are not passing a user-agent header that Facebook recognizes as a legitimate web browser that a real person might be using, as opposed to a bot or some other automated process.

Try passing a real web browser user agent, such as

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
```

That should get you past this particular error